# What's the "Reference" of a file shows in Process Explorer?

Tags: .net, filesystems, process-explorer

In our application we write multiple log files in different ways (via different libraries). One of the file will block from time to time when flushing it's buffer. The stack trace at that time is:

```
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.WriteFile(SafeFileHandle handle, Byte* bytes, Int32 numBytesToWrite, Int32& numBytesWritten, IntPtr mustBeZero)
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.WriteFile(SafeFileHandle handle, Byte* bytes, Int32 numBytesToWrite, Int32& numBytesWritten, IntPtr mustBeZero)
at System.IO.FileStream.WriteFileNative(SafeFileHandle handle, Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 count, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, Int32& hr)
at System.IO.FileStream.WriteCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.FileStream.FlushWrite(Boolean calledFromFinalizer)
at System.IO.FileStream.Flush(Boolean flushToDisk)
...
```

I've noticed that in Process Explorer (from Sysinternals Suites), the blocking file always has many "References":

[image: References]

But each of the other log files (which are always fine) has only 1 reference.

What's the "reference" of a file? Is it possible the reason that the file is blocked on flushing?

Comment: It counts references held by kernel code, underlying call is ObReferenceObject().  Very little reason for kernel code to be interested in a log file.  Except one, also what can make a WriteFile() call get stuck like that, anti-malware that turned viral.

Comment: Thanks, but how does managed code creates references to a file which is being written?

Comment: It doesn't.  Anti-malware doesn't have anything to do with managed code.